# Avast Remote Access Shield is blocking unknown remote access attempts to my computer (Win10) coming from a MacBook device on my LAN. [Confused]

Tags: windows, brute-force, macos, remote-desktop, lan

I need help understanding what is happening on my LAN and determine if a malicious attack is taking place.

The "attacks" started to occur for the first time last night. This morning, I open my computer to find over 100 remote-access attempts that were block by Avast (Avast Remote Access Shield labelled them as SMB:BruteFoce). The attacks always come in pairs and happen every minute or so. All attacks come from a specific IP address on my LAN and after verification, that address is attributed to a MacBook device that belongs to a family member in the household. I checked with the family member in person and nothing abnormal seem to be happening on the MacBook.

I am very confused. Does someone have an idea of what could be happening?
Should I be concerned for the security of my LAN? (I have already changed the pw just in case)

I would greatly appreciate incite from anybody who might have an idea of what is going on.

Thank you.

[image: Screen capture of Avast Remote Access Shield dashboard]

Comment: In the past, Avast opened ports in order to monitor attempted accesses and port scans, in esssence creating it's own concerns. This may be nothing more than the Mac enumerating the network and finding a bunch of Avast opened ports.

Comment: It is probably something like that. I'm pretty convinced it is not anything serious and that it must come from Avast. Thank you for your answer.